# Truthness of response objects in python

Tags: python, exception, response

I am using python requests library and i got 400 response.

I want to use the following code

```
data =  response.json() if response else ""
```

But it always shows `""` as response for 400 treated as false

```
(Pdb) self.response
<Response [400]>
(Pdb) assert self.response
*** AssertionError
```

Why is that

Comment: An http response code of 400 means "Bad Request", so treating the response object as `False` is reasonable, IMO.

Comment: @PM2Ring how can i check if response object is there and it has some data . because  even in 400 its has conetnt which tells error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [Response object](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py)'s `__bool__` returns the object's `ok` property, which in turn is `False` for any response 4xx or 5xx.

You can still examine the various fields of the Response, as described in [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response).

Comment: I had to use  `if response is not None` .  looks weird though :)

Comment: This is an...interesting design decision. An empty list, the integer 0, and an empty string (to pick a few examples) are all Falsey because you can't do anything meaningful with them: treating them as equivalent to None makes sense when you're testing the values. An HTTP error response, on the other hand, frequently contains an informative message in the body. It *should not* be Falsey; that's what the `ok` property is for.

Answer (score 1):

To add a little details to torek's answer above, only `400 <= self.status_code < 600`
 are False and the others are True for the object as you may see the related code of [Response object](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py) below.

```
def __bool__(self):
    """Returns true if :attr:`status_code` is 'OK'."""
    return self.ok

<snip>

@property
def ok(self):
    try:
        self.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError:
        return False
    return True

<snip>

def raise_for_status(self):
    """Raises stored :class:`HTTPError`, if one occurred."""

    http_error_msg = ''

    if 400 <= self.status_code < 500:
        http_error_msg = '%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, self.reason, self.url)

    elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
        http_error_msg = '%s Server Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, self.reason, self.url)

    if http_error_msg:
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```